# Python Selenium TypeError Expect 3 arguments (1given)

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am not able to solve the following issue :

Below is my python-selenium code.

```
import unittest
import time
import argparse, sys, os
import traceback
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class SeleniumTestPack(unittest.TestCase):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    timeout = 30

    def test_all(self):

        admin_base_url = args.url
        cognito_url = "test.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com"
        user_full_name = "test User"
        email = "test@test.com"
        firstName = "Selenium"
        lastName = "User"

        try:

          self.test_redirect_to_congito_login_page(admin_base_url, cognito_url)

          self.delete_geckodriver_log()

        except Exception:

          self.driver.save_screenshot('exception.png')
          self.fail("Exception: %s" % (traceback.format_exc()))

    def test_redirect_to_congito_login_page(self, admin_base_url, cognito_url):
      print "Test navigating to home page redirects to cognito login page"
      self.driver.get(admin_base_url)
      self.wait_for_element_loaded(By.ID, "div-forms")
      page_url = self.driver.current_url
      assert cognito_url in page_url

    def wait_for_element_loaded(self, id_type, id_locator):
      min_timeout = 2
      tries = 0
      retry_limit = 13
      while tries <= retry_limit:
        try:
          tries = tries + 1
          element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((id_type, id_locator))
          WebDriverWait(self.driver, min_timeout).until(element_present)
          break
        except Exception:
          if tries <= retry_limit:
            continue
          self.fail("Exception waiting for page to load %s : %s" % (id_locator,traceback.format_exc()))

    def delete_geckodriver_log(self):
      #running function at the end of all other invocation ensures all test cases have already ran successfully
      geckodriverfile="geckodriver.log"
      if os.path.isfile(geckodriverfile):
        os.remove(geckodriverfile)
      else:
        print("Error: %s file not found" % geckodriverfile)

    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
      # close the browser window
      self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
    parser.add_argument('--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--username',action='store',dest='username',default=None,help='<Required> username',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--password',action='store',dest='password',default=None,help='<Required> password',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('unittest_args', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.argv[1:] = args.unittest_args
    unittest.main()
```

I am running this test using below command.

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1280x1024x8" python admin-ui-test.py --url 'http://localhost:8080' --username 'test' --password 'test1234'
```

Below is my output:

```
ERROR: test_redirect_to_congito_login_page (__main__.SeleniumTestPack)  TypeError: test_redirect_to_congito_login_page() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Anything wrong i am doing? I have similar kind of tests at other places as well, Which are working fine since long time.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should change the `cognito_url = "test.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com"` to `cognito_url = "http://test.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com"`

Comment: @demouser123 No it is fine. That is handled by selenium internally. Please read my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very much new to me.

**The function name should not start with "test_"** (Otherwise it will be consider as a separate Test Case)

I renamed the function name and it is working fine!

Comment: Anyone knows what is ' def test_all(self)'?
I have taken this line of code from old tests.

Comment: Ok i got it. 
"Any method which starts with ``test_`` will considered as a test case." I.e i have 1 test case and inside that i have multiple small methods which perfomr individual tasks.